# Python Beginner Using Variables to change Tkinter Canvas Items

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am having a seemingly simple issue with getting the default value of variables to change. I am trying to make a rectangle drawn on a Tkinter Canvas to get smaller when I press a button. Any help in understanding how the variables work would be greatly appreciated. I am working in Python 3.6.
Here is a sample:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
bar_var=200

def test_callback():
    iteration = 100
    for iteration in range(0, iteration):
        bar_var -= 1
        bar_display.coords('bar', 0, 4, bar_var, 16)
        print("bar_var =" + str(bar_var))
bar_display = Canvas(root, height=20, width=200)
bar_display.grid(row=0, column=0)
bar_display.create_rectangle(0, 4, 200, 16, fill='blue', tag='bar')

button = Button(root, text="Resize Bar", command=test_callback)
button.grid(row=1, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried to change the "bar_var" variable to an example I found:

```
bar_var = None
    if bar_var():
        bar_var = 200
```

but this seems to throw an exception None Object type is not callable. Any help and explanation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `bar_var` is not defined as a local variable within your function. Even if you put a simple command like `bar_var += 2` into the function body, it will throw an error, because it doesn't know, what your variable is.

One way to overcome this problem, is to refer to the global variable, when calling the button function with, surprise, `global`:

```
def test_callback():
    global bar_var
    iteration = 20
    for iteration in range(iteration):
        bar_var -= 1
        bar_display.coords('bar', 0, 4, bar_var, 16)
        print("bar_var =" + str(bar_var))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Although for anyone wondering this did not update the Canvas item until the function ends and root.mainloop() was executed so to fix that problem I instead changed it to an if statement and set it to call the function for each draw update I wanted to force the mainloop to update the canvas items.